# Contextual Matching algorithm implementation in Python

Tags: python, information-retrieval, tf-idf

I have been trying to implement an algorithm using Python in order to perform contextual matching in a set of documents. My ultimate goal would be to be able to perform queries using positive keywords (and bigrams as well) but also negative ones. For instance a potential query could be:

`"food" + "healthy" - "children"`

which would target healthy foods for adults or expressed in a different manner, show me healthy food articles and leave out any articles that are about kids.

So far I have been using a simple tf-idf implementation with cosine similarity in order to be able to query my dataset.

Another thought I had is by using a Bag-of-Words model and set the `kid, kids, child, children` and many other words to null in order to exclude those results (and not should whether that would work as expected). Not sure how that would perform but sounds like a bad solution as there are bigrams as well in the text and queries that I should exclude and so on.

I know that what I am describing sounds a lot like [Word2vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec) and I tried to train a model but I should mention that I am not working with english text and I do not have enough data to get it working properly.

Any suggestions?